# Jest or Mocha: Dynamically create tests based on async initialization

Tags: asynchronous, mocha.js, jestjs

I'm trying to generate tests dynamically by looping over an array returned from an async call. I just cannot figure out how to do this - either using mocha or using jest. To illustrate using code, the following synchronous example works:

```
describe("Test using various frameworks", () => {
    ["mocha", "jest"].forEach(framework => {
        it(`Should test using ${framework}`, () => {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

However, if that array is fetched asynchronously, I cannot get the testing frameworks to wait until the array is fetched before trying to loop over it.

```
async function getFrameworks() {
    //TODO: get it from some async source here
    return ["mocha", "jest"];
}

describe("Test using various frameworks", () => {
    var frameworks;
    //before() instead of beforeAll() if using mocha
    beforeAll(async ()=> {
        frameworks = await getFrameworks();
    });

    frameworks.forEach(framework => {
        it(`Should test using ${framework}`, () => {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

This fails saying `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. I've tried all sort of combinations of using `async/await` and `Promise` and passing in a `done` callback but to no avail.

The closest I came to this was using Mocha's [--delay](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite) flag, but that only solves part of the problem. What I really want to do in my actual use case is to **run some async intialization in the `before()` or `beforeAll()` hooks which I then use to dynamically generate tests.**

Any pointers on how to do this using either mocha or jest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I did not find a way to do this using Jest or Mocha, but I could accomplish it using [tap](http://www.node-tap.org/) - which I used through [babel-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-tap).

```
import tap from "babel-tap";

async function getFrameworks() {
    //TODO: get it from some async source here
    return ["mocha", "jest"];
}

getFrameworks().then(frameworks => {
    frameworks.forEach(framework => {
        tap.test(`Should test using ${framework}`, (tester) => {
            tester.ok("It works!");
        });
    }); 
});
```

You can do a lot more though. You can create nested scopes by further calling `tester.test()` for example. Also, since `tap` does not have the concept of `before`, `after` etc, (unless you use the [Mocha-like DSL](http://www.node-tap.org/mochalike/) ), you can simply use imperative code to simulate the equivalent behavior.

Also, you can freely use `async/await` style calls inside tests.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha has [some support async tests](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code). Specifically, your `it()` callback can be async. Here is how to rearrange your tests to *"looping over an array returned from an async call"*:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const { expect } = require('chai');

function getMyTestData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(['mocha', 'jest']), 1000));
}

describe('Test using various frameworks', () => {
  it('Should test by looping over an array returned from an async call', async () => {
    const myTestData = await getMyTestData();
    for(let datum of myTestData) {
      expect(datum.length).greaterThan(4, `Data '${datum}' not long enough`);
    }
  })
});
```