# undefined var inside test.each global when using async beforeAll - Jest 24

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, jestjs

I have a test which makes an API call, creates an array of strings and then iterates through them inside an `it` block using [Jest `test.each` global](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout)

```
describe('Something fancy', () => {
  let strings;

  beforeAll(async (done) => {
    strings = await getStrings() // returns an array (e.g. ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
    done(); // as per https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#callbacks
  });

  test.each(strings)('string %s here', async (string) => {
    console.log(string); // undefined
    console.log(strings); // undefined
  };
};
```

for some reason, `test.each` runs synchronously and "does not wait" for `getStrings` to resolve, whereas if I turn `test.each` into a regular `it('tests something', () => { console.log(strings) });`, strings do get logged as expected:

```
  it('tests something', async () => {
    console.log(strings); // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  })
```

Why is this happening and is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks inside of Jest methods are executed asynchronously so at the moment of executing `test.each(strings)` the `strings` value is still undefined.

There are a few ways to get around this:

1. Prepare data outside of the test run. For example, add a `pretest` npm script

```
"pretest": "node prepare-data.js"
"test": "jest"
```

In `prepare-data.js` you can call `getStrings()` and write the result to a temporary file, which will be picked up in test

2. Use [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) to wrap asynchronous calls
3. Switch to a different test runner which supports generating test cases dynamically. An example is described in this question: [Jest or Mocha: Dynamically create tests based on async initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240468/jest-or-mocha-dynamically-create-tests-based-on-async-initialization)

Comment: makes sense, and thanks for the recommending node-fibers!